# tsc does not compile import statement

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

While I'm using Node.js + Typescript, tsc does not compile import statement.
My goal is compile entities and migrate with TypeORM.

Here is my code.

file structure

```
node
  app
    entities
      User.ts
  lib
  ormconfig.json
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "app",
        "outDir": "lib",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "allowJs": false,
        "target": "es2019",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": ["es5", "es6", "es2018", "esnext.asynciterable", "es2019", "es2020.string", "es2020.symbol.wellknown"],
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": ["app"]
  }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js -d ormconfig.json",
    "build": "echo 'build server...' && tsc -b .",
    "server": "tsc && node lib/server.js",
    "db:sync": "typeorm schema:sync",
    "db:migrate:generate": "typeorm migration:generate -d migration -n",
    "db:migrate:revert": "typeorm migration:revert",
    "db:migration": "typeorm migration:run"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@typegoose/typegoose": "^9.9.0",
    "apollo-server-core": "^3.9.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.9.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "graphql-depth-limit": "^1.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.8",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/graphql-depth-limit": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0"
  }
}
```

ormconfig.json

```
{
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3306,
  "username": "root",
  "password": "test",
  "database": "test",
  "migrationsTableName": "migrations",
  "entities": ["app/entities/*.ts"],
  "migrations": ["migration/*.ts"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/entities",
    "migrationsDir": "migration"
  },
  "autoSchemaSync": true
}
```

BEFORE COMPILING
node/app/entities/User.ts

```
import { GraphQLInt, GraphQLString } from "graphql";
import { Field, ObjectType } from "type-graphql";
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
@ObjectType({
  description: 'User',
  isAbstract: false  // true면 DTO 확장하여 inputType으로도 사용할 수 있다.
})
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => GraphQLInt, { description: 'user id' })
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'int', comment: 'user id' })
  readonly userId!: number

  @Field(() => GraphQLString, { description: 'user name' })
  @Column('varchar', { nullable: false, comment: 'user name', length: 10 })
  name!: string

  @Field(() => GraphQLString, { description: 'user phone without hyphen(-)', nullable: false })
  @Column('varchar', { nullable: false, comment: 'user phone without hyphen(-)', length: 174 })
  phone!: string
}
```

And When I do "tsc -b ."
AFTER COMPILING

node/lib/entities/User.js

```
"use strict";
// import { GraphQLInt, GraphQLString } from "graphql";
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
var __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.User = void 0;
const graphql_1 = require("graphql");
const type_graphql_1 = require("type-graphql");
const typeorm_1 = require("typeorm");
let User = class User extends typeorm_1.BaseEntity {
};
__decorate([
    (0, type_graphql_1.Field)(() => graphql_1.GraphQLInt, { description: 'user id' }),
    (0, typeorm_1.PrimaryGeneratedColumn)({ type: 'int', comment: 'user id' }),
    __metadata("design:type", Number)
], User.prototype, "userId", void 0);
__decorate([
    (0, type_graphql_1.Field)(() => graphql_1.GraphQLString, { description: 'user name' }),
    (0, typeorm_1.Column)('varchar', { nullable: false, comment: 'user name', length: 10 }),
    __metadata("design:type", String)
], User.prototype, "name", void 0);
__decorate([
    (0, type_graphql_1.Field)(() => graphql_1.GraphQLString, { description: 'user phone without hyphen(-)', nullable: false }),
    (0, typeorm_1.Column)('varchar', { nullable: false, comment: 'user phone without hyphen(-)', length: 174 }),
    __metadata("design:type", String)
], User.prototype, "phone", void 0);
User = __decorate([
    (0, typeorm_1.Entity)(),
    (0, type_graphql_1.ObjectType)({
        description: 'User',
        isAbstract: false // true면 DTO 확장하여 inputType으로도 사용할 수 있다.
    })
], User);
exports.User = User;
```

tsc automatically hide import statement so migration would not work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the compiled statement is right there in line 14: `const graphql_1 = require("graphql");`

Comment: ++ to what CherryDT said, also waht are you doing with the compiled code? its not supposed to be manually dealt with

Comment: I was trying to use migrate and there was a problem with compiled js file.